# Worker thread needs to access UI

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and programming in C++ / Xaml. I have a worker thread that splits off from the UI thread to do some calculations. I need this worker thread to be able to access components such as a TextBox or a ProgressBar on the user interface to do things like inform the user on its progress. After some research this is apparently way harder than I anticipated.

Comment: Decouple data processing and user interface. You might make the change in the data processing available through an event.

Answer (score 0):

You may think the worker threads need to access the UI, but you should re-think that idea, it is a bad approach. You already found out that it is *way harder than anticipated* - look at this as an indicator that you may be on the wrong track.

The better way is to use indirection, i.e. to post a message, raise an event or signal a flag whenever there are new data available to display. The UI thread handles this and does whatever he needs to do when it is appropriate.

This way you leave room for future improvements, e.g. you may wish to replace the graphical UI by some other version (progress bar instead of a percent label) or a completely different UI later (think web-based, think service without own UI, etc).

Having a worker thread accessing controls directly ties your background worker code too closely to a concrete UI, which is nothing more than an arbitrary restriction that comes with no gain<sup>1)</sup>. By using an indirection (this could be even an properly synchronized view model) you prevent this, making later changes a snap.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Who says YAGNI? You already need it, right now!</sub>